# Docker not recognising psycopg2-binary as psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, ubuntu, psycopg2

Using pipenv I have the following pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
flask = "*"
uuid = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
psycopg2-binary = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

And then my Dockerfile is set up as follows:

```
FROM python:3.8.3-slim-buster

RUN useradd deploy_trial

WORKDIR /home/deploy_trial

RUN pip install pipenv

COPY . /home/deploy_trial/

RUN pipenv install --deploy

CMD ["python","./app/text.py"]
```

However, although the build seems to go successfully, when I run the image I get an error message saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app/text.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

So it obviously thinks that psycopg2 hasn't been installed... This is really strange because when I have used psycopg2-binary on my local machine and all of my programs there recognise the installation as psycopg2 when the code is run.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried: `apt install -y python3-psycopg2`?

Comment: @K4liber So remove psycopg2-binary from the pipfile and then add what you wrote in the dockerfile with RUN on the line before CMD?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, try to add `RUN python -m pip list` after the `pipenv install` and check if the `psycopg2-binary` is listed.

Comment: So all I get when I do that is: certifi          2021.10.8
distlib          0.3.4
filelock         3.4.2
pip              20.1.1
pipenv           2022.1.8
platformdirs     2.4.1
setuptools       47.1.1
six              1.16.0
virtualenv       20.13.0
virtualenv-clone 0.5.7
wheel            0.34.2

Comment: why are you using a `pipenv` inside a container, seems redundant..., also based on what `pip` lists it is clear that `python` is not pointing to wherever `pipenv` is installing these packages

Comment: Thanks - pipenv was obviously messing with something, because switching to pip installing all of the packages worked.  Not a problem with psycopg2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.3-slim-buster

RUN python -m pip install pipenv

COPY script.py script.py
COPY Pipfile Pipfile
RUN pipenv install

CMD ["pipenv", "run", "python", "script.py"]
```

script.py:

```
import psycopg2

print('it is ok')
```

Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
psycopg2-binary = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

It works with such configuration.